# How to access an array in j-query returned by php script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to access an array in J-query returned by PHP script via Ajax call

Ajax call for getting result from PHP script:

```
    $.ajax({
               url: "http://localhost/WCPM/index.php/demand/check_demand_status",
               type: 'GET',
               cache: true,
               data: {
                Meter_Group_Name: $(this).val()
               },
               success: function(data) {
               if(data["exists"]==1){
                 alert("Request already in pending for this Group");
                 $('#Meter_Group_Name').attr('selectedIndex',0);    
               }
              $("select#meter_number").html(data["option"]);
            }
    });
```

Response of Ajax Call from Php script:

```
     Array
        (
            [exists] => 1
            [option] => <option value=''>Please Select Meter</option>
<option value='5'>222000</option>
    <option value='6'>101010</option><option value='7'>34500A</option>
    <option value='13'>A00001</option><option value='14'>A11149</option>
    <option value='15'>000123</option><option value='16'>A00003</option>
    <option value='17'>A00002</option>
        )
```

Html Select Tag where option field to be store

```
   <select name="Meter_Numbers" id="meter_number"></select>
```

How to check **data["exists"]==1** in jquery code and populate select in html with 
**data["option"]**?

Comment: Try returning the array as a json object using json_encode()

Answer (score 1):

You can use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) here like,

in `js` `ajax function`

Add type:

```
$.ajax({
     url:'',
     data:'',
     dataType:'json',//add this line
```

Refer **datatype** in [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

In **PHP** Script use `json_encode function` like,

```
echo json_encode($yourarray);
return;
```